# Jquery - Remove Tags and add Tags dynamically using [aehlke] multitags plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using tagit plugin (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it "Tagit Plugin aehlke") and auto-complete feature. I have to change tags based on the selection made using the auto-complete feature.

It worked for the first selection but not for the second one .

I removed the existing tags - using 'removeAll" in tagit plugin and did tagit() - doesn't work ??

This is my code :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()  {
        var allKeyWordsString=" ";
            $.ajax({
                url : some url,
                type : 'GET',
                //data : "query="+$("#query").val(),
                async : false,
                cache : false,
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                processData : false,
                success : function(returndata) {

                    allKeyWordsString = returndata.success;
                    alert("keywords are "+ allKeyWordsString);
                }
            });
var sampleTags = allKeyWordsString.split(',');   

      $("#keyWordForm").autocomplete({
      source: sampleTags,
      minLength : 3,

      select: function(event,ui){
        var selectedKeyWord = ui.item.value;


        var services = " ";
            $.ajax({
                url : 'some url',
                type : 'GET',
                data : "query="+selectedKeyWord+" services",
                async : false,
                cache : false,
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                processData : false,
                success : function(returndata) {
                    services = returndata.success;
                    alert(" ajax call response is "+services);
                }
            });
            if ($('#servicesForm').val().length != 0){
            $('#servicesForm').tagit('removeAll');
            }
            document.getElementById("servicesForm").value=services;         

            $('#servicesForm').tagit();
      }
    });     

return false;
        });
</script>
```

Please help

Comment: It would be easier to figure out problem, if a jsfiddle would have been included

Comment: I have to add an external javascript file, i couldn't add that in jsFiddle. any alternative ??

Comment: @user2640863 You can use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) and just add your external js file in the html section.

Answer (score 2):

To add tag, you can use method createTag:

```
$("#myTags").tagit("createTag", "brand-new-tag");
```

Similarly, method removeTagByLabel is for removing a tag:

```
$("#myTags").tagit("removeTagByLabel", "my-tag");
```

You can find above methods in the documentation: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown